# installing sqlalchemy on AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I new to set-up the environment in AWS Glue, I am importing sqlalchemy in my AWS Glue using

```
import sqlalchemy
```

But I am getting NoModuleFound error. I searched and found that I have to create a wheel file for the same.

can anybody give me link from where i can find this wheel file online.

And also on how to extract the wheel file from s3 and import sqlalchemy.

link of the wheel file and steps on how to use that file to import the library in AWS Glue